# Which package will provide pygtk, gtk, pyserial and libsvg2-common for Inkscape extension

Tags: xubuntu, gtk

I have Xubuntu 16.04 installed. I need to install an Inkscape extension which requires

```
pygtk and gtk
pyserial
librsvg2-common
```

When I do `apt-get install pygtK` or `apt-get install libgtk` I get the message

```
unable to locate package ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. I needed to install `libgtk2.0` or `libgtk3.0`.